# SQL Replace Hex String

Tags: sql, replace, hex, arabic

I'm working on an Arabic (WordPress) site with tens of thousands of posts and need to search-and-replace some links in the post_content but am getting inconsistent results which I think might be because the string that I'm searching for is a hexadecimal version of the Arabic word. For example, in this case I want to search for links to `team/ليفربول` and replace them with `team/liverpool` except I actually have to search for `%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84` which is ليفربول (Liverpool) in hex.

A SELECT returns the expected ~300 results:

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_posts` WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%/team/%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84%'
```

But when I perform a dry run on the UPDATE SQL query it returns 0 affected rows instead of the expected ~300.

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `post_content` = REPLACE(`post_content`, '/team/%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84', '/team/liverpool') WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%/team/%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%A8%D9%88%D9%84%';
```

I suspect that SQL has issue with the `%` characters in the string and wonder whether I need to somehow escape the whole string in order for SQL to treat those not as wildcards but as they appear.

Comment: Are you not able to use the actual Arabic string? 
**eg.** `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'team/ليفربول', 'team/liverpool');`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content, 'team/ليفربول', 'team/liverpool');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_excerpt = REPLACE (post_excerpt, 'team/ليفربول', '/team/liverpool');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'team/ليفربول','/team/liverpool');
UPDATE wp_termmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (meta_value, 'team/ليفربول','/team/liverpool');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_content = REPLACE (comment_content, 'team/ليفربول', '/team/liverpool');
UPDATE wp_comments SET comment_author_url = REPLACE (comment_author_url, 'team/ليفربول','/team/liverpool');
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (guid, 'team/ليفربول', '/team/liverpool') WHERE post_type = 'attachment';
```

Also might be worth checking that your proceeding `/` is not affecting your results.

I was able to use the Arabic string to match a `post_content` record by adding a hyperlink to a post:

[image: SQL Match Example]
[image: post_content example]

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, Aquious. I can't search using the Arabic string in this case unfortunately because the slug has been stored in the DB in the hexadecimal format. They actually vary between Ar and hex and I'll need to do find and replace for both formats but querying the Arabic strings is fine, it's only the hex ones that cause me problems.

Comment: For context, the hex is being stored when editors add a URL to their post content which has been copied from the browser address bar, and therefore always comes out as hex.